# https redirect with an exception (errors)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I need to redirect all **http** requests to **https** except /sports-scores, /sport-scores/, and sport-scores.html pages.

I've been at it for two hours. My brain is fried and I can't make sense any sense from this.

```
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName www.my-domain.com
        ServerAlias my-domain.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        RewriteEngine on
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors-www.log

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName www.my-domain.com
        ServerAlias my-domain.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile   /home/user/gandi-ssl/www.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/gandi-ssl/server.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/user/gandi-ssl/www.crt
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors-www.log

        RewriteEngine On
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to redirect all http requests to https except /sports-scores,
>   /sport-scores/, and sport-scores.html pages.

You need to adjust your 80 Virtual Host config and use the below rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ServerAlias my-domain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors-www.log

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sports-scores
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ServerAlias my-domain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile   /home/user/gandi-ssl/www.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/gandi-ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/user/gandi-ssl/www.crt
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors-www.log

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sports-scores
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </VirtualHost>
```

Let me know how this works out.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. When I land on the homepage I get redirected to HTTPS://homepage.com, that's good. Then I click on a link on my homepage that loads /sports-scores  page, and that's loaded over HTTPS. I need that specific page on my site loaded over HTTP and if it's over HTTPS I need it redirected back to HTTP.

Comment: Well it appeared it did work. But it wasn't clear that if you are **already** on https you needed to redirected back. So then you need the opposite rule too in the 443 virtual host. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I need redirect back from HTTPS to HTTP for /sports-scores page only. I tried the new code and I get This webpage has a redirect loop 
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS I'm sorry to be such a pain!!

Comment: The request uri condition should take care of the redirect loop. Can you restart apache and clear your browser cache and try again?

Comment: Rebooted, restarted, cleared cache. When I click on /sports-scores from HTTPS homepage, I get redirected back to the home page. What I would like to happen is HTTPS traffic to get redirected to HTTP traffic, from https://domain.com/sports-scores >> http://domain.com/sports-scores Right now I get redirected to the home page when I click on https://domain.com/sports-scores

Comment: From error log when I click on  /sports-scores page link from homepage : RewriteCond: input='/index.php' pattern='^/sport(s)?-scores(\\.html)?' => not-matched

Comment: It seems like it's trying to use index.php. Anyway, I adjusted the answer to check for just that specific URI /sports-scores

Comment: No, sorry. I get redirected to /index.php when I click on the /sports-scores link from / the home page. Forwarding from https to http works only if I use RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^off in virtualhost:80. However, this does not redirect all other http to https traffic.